# spark program run on local system but it doesnt run on server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a spark program that written in Java. After creating a jar file out of it, I can run it on local system. But when I want to run it on a remote server it gives me an error like this:

> ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 10, 192.168.230.2):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I need to mention that I have the exact same version of spark.
what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you add your spark-submit? This is generally because the file is there in local environment but not all executors have access to that file or data.

Comment: Spark is **not** SPARQL or what's the reason for adding this tag?

Comment: And obviously, you have a NullPointerException. Please show the line number, i.e. the whole StackTrace. I guess it might happen because some file etc. is not found when you use the program on the server. But it's just a guess without seeing the whole Error

Comment: Try with master yarn-client. you might see the issue.